# How to separate each music notes from one to another in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have been given some frequencies and notes to play a music.

```
tnote= [1,1,1/2,1/2,1,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,1];
fnote=[493.92, 587.36, 587.36, 659.28 659.28,784,741,784,741,784,587.36,587.36,659.28,659.28];
```

My sampling frequency

```
Fs= 8000;
```

I used for loop so that i could use every tnote from `tnote(1)` to `tnote(14)`and fnote from `fnote(1)` to `fnote(14)` in sinusoidal wave.

```
for i= 1:14

    if tnote(i)==1
        t=zeros(1,8001);
    elseif tnote(i)==1/2
        t=zeros(1,4001);
    elseif tnote(i)==1/4
        t=zeros(1,2001);
    end

t= 0:1/Fs:tnote(i);

   x= sin(2*pi*fnote(i)*t)
```

To play song

```
soundsc(x,11025)
    end
```

It felt like the notes are nested. I didn't understand why the notes are not waiting previous note to stop. How will i make it right in matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when Matlab starts playing a note it doesnt't wait until it ends. Playing a sound is apparently an independent process, and Matlab goes on with the rest of the programm immediately. As a result the notes get stacked.

To play them sequentially you need to create a larger `x` that contains all notes one after the other, and at the end of the program play that. For example:

```
tnote= [1,1,1/2,1/2,1,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/4,1/2,1/2,1/2,1/2,1];
fnote=[493.92, 587.36, 587.36, 659.28 659.28,784,741,784,741,784,587.36,587.36,659.28,659.28]

Fs= 8000;
x = [];
for i= 1:14
    if tnote(i)==1
        t=zeros(1,8001);
    elseif tnote(i)==1/2
        t=zeros(1,4001);
    elseif tnote(i)==1/4
        t=zeros(1,2001);
    end
    t= 0:1/Fs:tnote(i);
    x = [x sin(2*pi*fnote(i)*t)]; %// attach new note after the others
end
soundsc(x, Fs) %// you had 11025 instead of Fs. Was it intentional?
```

You should also consider preallocating `x` instead of havint it growin the loop. But in this case it's probably not very important.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it was given by the assistant intentionally. He says 'use playing frequency 11025 in soundsc().'

Comment: But note that if the sampling rate and `Fs` are different then the actual frequencies of the notes played will not be those in `fnote`.  They will be scaled